# VNC connections denied using built in screenshare on Mac

Tags: mac, vnc, macos-bigsur

I'm hoping this is on topic here.

I was tasked with getting a mac mini to be accessible remotely for file dumping. The general instructions for this are pretty straight forward. Go to settings, sharing, and enabling all the expected options. This all worked within the network. In office, we can connect without issues and share files. But remotely, nobody can connect. We get this error:

```
Unable to communicate with “19x.xxx.xx.xxx”.  
Make sure the remote computer is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing.
```

We already made sure the computer is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing. We also made sure all the permissions for access were set accordingly. Anyone can connect. I haven't messed with router things. I'm not exactly a network technician so I just go by the instructions. We also disabled firewalls on the machines trying to connect remotely. No change.

Unfortunately, the instructions pretty much end there and don't tell you what to do if you get this error.

I tried connecting via file manager -> go -> connect to network and put the VNC IP as well as tried with the ports as others have suggested. vnc://19x.xxx.xx.xxx:5900 etc and it does the same thing.

Seems like this has to be something obvious. I would absolutely hate to pay a monthly fee to use someone's VNC software for something we will use infrequently. I don't mind paying a one time fee though. So options outside the default tools are open to consideration. We prefer to keep it simple if possible though.

If it helps to know, the remote machine is on Big Sur. The Mac we're connecting to is on Monterey. I wondered if anyone knew of other things to check that might be along the lines of (doh, how did I not check that) kind of things.

Thanks

Comment: "put the VNC IP" - you need the router's external IP. You then need to set up the router for port forwarding to the mini. …& you need to not be on CGNAT, or you'll have to buy a fixed IP address. Knowing what IP you're trying to connect to [at least the first two numbers] might help us know where you're currently aiming. This is why such as TeamViewer, NoMachine etc are so popular - they avoid having to punch a hole in a secure system, traversing devices outside your control.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks! The first digits are 19. I read that port forwarding may be necessary, and I will look into how I might do that. I'm not sure how to tell if we are on CGNAT but I can google around a bit.

Comment: I meant the first two entire fields… but if we're starting 19 let me guess the first two are 192.168. That unfortunately will get you nowhere. That's a private IP address range, valid only inside a network. It cannot work across borders such as your router. Go to google & ask it "What's my IP address?" That will tell you the external IP. Give us the first two fields of that.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yes, you're right. 192.168. Does a private IP range mean that we don't have options within the built in tools and we have to go with a service like TeamViewer? My remote IP begins with 184.179 - I will need to have someone check the IP of the office machine...

Comment: Not necessarily - but you haven't yet got outside the building to see what options you have.

Comment: @Tetsujin - the office IP begins with 209.104

Comment: At least that looks like a non-NATted address, so what you want is likely possible. You need to do a whole lot more research now you're armed with some terminology - investigate how port forwarding works on your router for starters.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I will do just that. Thanks for all your help! I'll ping back if it goes well and can get your suggestions turned into an answer so I can accept it.